# More complex search result sorting - Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am using the Tire gem to perform search in my application. In my controller, I perform the search:

```
@results = Model.search(query: params[:query])
```

I then want to re-sort the results using a custom sorting method

```
@results.each_with_hit do |result|
      # complex math that computes final score.
      # calculations include model attributes and _score field
      # ...
      # modify score for the result
      result[1]["_score"] = final_score 
end
```

I tried sorting the results with the new score by doing:

```
@results.each_with_hit.sort_by {|r| r[1][_score]}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know about the [`custom_score`](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/custom_score_queries_test.rb) query and you have some specific requirements which rule out using it. Do note, that you can access document attributes in the script (see linked integration test), so it's worth exploring it thoroughly.

If you *really* want to resort just the limited results returned by the query (thus potentially making the calculation incorrect), the `Enumerable#sort_by` method really should work fine:

```
require 'tire'

Tire.index 'articles' do
  delete
  create

  store title: 'One',   views: 10
  store title: 'Two',   views: 30
  store title: 'Three', views: 20
  store title: 'Four',  views: 10

  refresh
end

s = Tire.search('articles') { query { string 'title:T*' } }

s.results.

  # Sort by sum of title length and views
  #
  sort_by do |d|
    d.title.size + d.views
  end.

  # Sort in descending order
  #
  reverse.

  # Print results
  #
  each do |d|
    puts "* #{d.title} (#{d.title.size + d.views})"
  end
```

It should work the same way for plain documents as for models.

Comment: The issue that I am facing is that once I do this I loose the ability to paginate the results in my view. I'd like to sort the array of results inside the `Tire::Results::Collection` class

Comment: Can I access the search's `max_score` value in the `custom_score` approach?